# On pronting view I set body to `display: none;` and the texts to `display: block !important;` but nothing is showing

Tags: html, css

The code is:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    display: block !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

p {
    display: block !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-align: justify !important;
}
```

I ran out of ideas what can be the problem. I think it's a very basic misitake I did just i cant see where.

Comment: you *never* make the body display:none.

Comment: @TemaniAfif `body { .. display: none; }`?

Answer (score 1):

Your body has `display: none` . Since the body is a wrapper for your other elements, they will never show.